# MySQL Find and Replace for Tablepress Plugin for WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using Tablepress plugin for WordPress. I'm trying to do a find/replace of all 'http://' to replace with 'https://'.

I've used the Search and Replace plugin, but this does not touch the Tablepress content.

I know that I can write a SQL command to search find/replace in phpMyAdmin, but I am not a SQL expert so not sure exactly how to structure the command.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

update `your_table` set `your_column` = replace(`your_column`, 'http://', 'https://')